# python / windows - can't install lasio python package - RequirementParseError

Tags: python, windows, pip, conda

I use Python 3.6 on Windows and can't install the lasio package. This is the output I get when launching

```
pip install lasio
```

from anaconda prompt cmd

```
Collecting lasio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/25/60f49906d6a8bc46b2a78488f58a0f6c123c45494abc105eed9dcf0c2f87/lasio-0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\name surname\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lasio) (1.15.2)
Collecting ordereddict (from lasio)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2883, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2677, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 93, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1654, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1644, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3417, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1406, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3205, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 33), (line:1, col:34)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2963, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8], e.msg
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'; extra '": Expected stringEnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 349, in run
    self._warn_about_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 475, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 98, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 41, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2621, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2885, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2895, in _compute_dependencies
    reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2956, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)
  File "C:\Users\name surname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2965, in __init__
    raise RequirementParseError(str(e))
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Parse error at "'; extra '": Expected stringEnd
```

I really cannot find any solution on google about this. Might it be a pip configuration problem? It's not the first time I get this kind of errors on windows and they're pretty annoying...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm the maintainer of lasio - the only requirements are numpy and ordereddict. You could try `pip install ordereddict` and separately install numpy, to see where the problem is. I suspect it's to do with the Anaconda installation :-(

Comment: I had to reset the python environment...